# Why do I get “variable referenced from scope but not defined” error from Ormlite on .net, but it works well on Mono?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack Ormlite. My code likes this:

```
var number = _conn.Count<Lot>(lot => lot.Labels.Contains("lookingString"));
```

My problem is the code works well on Mono, but get error from .Net framework:

```
Message: [InvalidOperationException: variable 'lot' of type 'pM.Models.Entity.Lot' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined]

 System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage):142
 System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node):10
 System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node):59
 System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node):13
 System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node):12
 System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes):26
 System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node):88
 System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator):0
 ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m):87
 ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b):135
 ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Where(Expression`1 predicate):12
 ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadExpressionCommandExtensions.Scalar[T,TKey](IDbCommand dbCmd, Expression`1 field, Expression`1 predicate):26
 ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter):16
 pM.Api.LabelReadHelper.GetUsage[T](String labelName) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\b85b83a981467d5b\pM.Api\Common\Labels\Template\LabelReadHelper.cs:23
```

On Mono, LastSql like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Lot` WHERE (upper(`Labels`) like '%lookingString%' AND (`CustomerId` = 'a54f02ee-cc74-4b4d-845d-6db2efb1f5dc'));
```

My ServiceStack.Ormlite version is 4.0.50.

Is the Contains method works different between the platform?

Comment: Please see the code on: http://gistlyn.com/?gist=cbf0ced50b86c9881d5178d39d613cda&collection=74d7b0467a197f678bb4220b2c301ac3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in the latest **v4.0.62** of OrmLite which you can [try out Live in Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=2bc6769ff2e85388b79f9cb1572292d5):

```
public class Lot
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Labels { get; set; }
}

db.CreateTable<Lot>();

db.Insert(new Lot { Labels = "foo" });
db.Insert(new Lot { Labels = "bar" });
db.Insert(new Lot { Labels = "qux" });
db.Insert(new Lot { Labels = "foo,bar,qux" });

var count = db.Count<Lot>(x => x.Labels.Contains("bar"));

"Labels with 'bar': {0}".Print(count); //= 2
```

It has the same behavior in Mono/Linux which you can try by using `mono.gistlyn.com` instead, e.g:

- http://gistlyn.com/?gist=2bc6769ff2e85388b79f9cb1572292d5 (Windows)
- http://mono.gistlyn.com/?gist=2bc6769ff2e85388b79f9cb1572292d5 (Mono)

Comment: Hi mythz, I just updated the test to reproduce the issue: 

http://gistlyn.com/?gist=cbf0ced50b86c9881d5178d39d613cda&collection=74d7b0467a197f678bb4220b2c301ac3


It got same exception on the gistlyn, but it works for my Mono version.
I also got the same issue for other methods, such as Select<T> etc.

Comment: @TomWu You can't add indirection like that, the generic `T` param needs to be of a concrete Table class OrmLite can map back to a Table POCO.